# Memory management with and without the virtual destructor

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++11

Why virtual destructor makes these differeces in the memory management?

I have a class:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() : m_x(0) { }
    ~A() {}
public:
    static ptrdiff_t member_offset(const A &a)
    {
        const char *p = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&a);
        const char *q = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&a.m_x);

        std::cout << "\n&a   =" << &a << "\n&a.mx=" << &a.m_x << "\np=" << (int)p << " q=" << (int)q << '\n';

        return q - p;
    }
private:
    int m_x;
};
```

and if I call the `A a; member_offset(a);` I get printed:

```
&a   =002EFD28
&a.mx=002EFD28
p=3079464 q=3079464
```

an if I make the destructor `virtual`, I am getting other addresses:

```
&a   =002EFD28
&a.mx=002EFD2C
p=3079464 q=3079468
```

Why? What influence has virtual destructor on memory management?

Comment: I guess you pasted the wrong set of addresses for the second case...

Comment: Aren't `p` and `q` different, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With no virtual functions (and meeting various other constraints), the class has *standard layout*, and its first data member is guaranteed to have the same address as the object itself.

With one or more virtual functions, it is *polymorphic* and no longer has standard layout, and there is no such guarantee. Typically, polymorphism is implemented by adding a hidden pointer (sometimes known as the *virtual pointer* or *vptr*) to the class, pointing to the class-specific virtual function table (sometimes known as the *vtable*) and other dynamic type information. In this case, it looks like this pointer comes before the declared members, leading to the difference in addresses that you observe.

Answer (score 6):

A virtual method table pointer is added to each instance of the class - typically at the beginning of the object. It doesn't have to be a destructor, any first `virtual` method will determine the generation of a virtual method table.

Comment: Oh, yes, I forgot about virtual method table... But between `&a` and `&a.m_x` will always be a difference of 4, because it is just the address of the virtual method table, no mather how many virtual methods?